# matching a group of words by regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to change:

> `'1foo 1.5f/b 1 Foo Bar'`

to:

> `"1fb 1.5fb 1fb"`

this is my code:

```
re.sub(r"(?i)\b(\d+\.*\d*)\s*(f\/b|foo|foo bar)\b",r"\1fb",'1foo 1.5f/b 1 Foo Bar')
```

but what I get is:

> `'1fb 1.5fb 1fb Bar'`

This is because both **foo** and **foo bar** are in the match group. How can I avoid Bar being in the output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```sh
(?i)(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?:f/b|foo(?: bar)?)\b
```

And replace using `\1fb`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rzQ5fP/1)

**Code:**

```sh
import re

s = '1foo 1.5f/b 1 Foo Bar'

r = re.sub(r'(?i)(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?:f/b|foo(?: bar)?)\b', r'\1fb', s)
```

**Output:**

```
1fb 1.5fb 1fb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch `foo` and `foo bar` i.e. `foo|foo bar` would be `foo bar|foo`

```
re.sub(r"(?i)\b(\d+\.*\d*)\s*(f\/b|foo bar|foo)\b",r"\1fb",'1foo 1.5f/b 1 Foo Bar')
```

Output:

`1fb 1.5fb 1fb`